# What is wrong with package-lock.json in CircleCI?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, circleci, circleci-2.0

If I don't remove the `package-lock.json` before installing the node modules in CircleCI, I get the following quirky error:

> enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/circleci/AZTEC/aztec-crypto-js/node_modules/ajv' -> '/home/circleci/AZTEC/aztec-crypto-js/node_modules/.ajv.DELETE'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

If I add the following step in my build job:

```
- run:
   name: "Remove Package Lock"
   command: rm package-lock.json
```

Everything works fine, although I don't think this is okay because afaik `package-lock.json` **should** be committed.

Using node 8.11.3 and npm 5.6.0 on CircleCI version 2 and node 10.12.0 and npm 6.5.0 on my local machine.